# Python TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, list, set, typeerror

I'm trying to run a program which is effectively doing the following:

`if [4, 5, False, False, False, False] in {}`

And, on this line, I'm getting a `TypeError: unhashable type 'list'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have data structures that look something along the lines of [4,5,False,False,False,False] and I want to find them within an unordered list of items. {} was an example (that my code happened to be failing on at the time) of such a thing. I'm now using a list instead of a dictionary, and it's working out better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code `if foo in {}` checks if any of the keys of the dictionary is equal to `foo`.

In your example, `foo` is a list. A list is an unhashable type, and cannot be the key of a dictionary.

If you want to check if *any* entry of a list is contained in a dictionaries' keys or in a set, you can try:

`if any([x in {} for x in (4, 5, False)])`.

If you want to check if any of your values is equal to your list, you can try:

`if any([v == [4, 5, False, False, False, False] for v in your_dict.values()])`

Answer (score 1):

A `set` holds hashable objects, which means that they are sortable and it enables efficient search/insert method.
On the other hand a `list` is not hashable. That's why your code makes error.
I recommend to use `tuple` instead of `list`.

```
if (4, 5, False, False, False, False) in {}:
  ...
```

Comment: This is still more efficiently written as `if False:`. It would be more useful if the OP told us what s/he really wants to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that tuples can be used as dictionary keys instead of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
if all(x in {} for x in [4, 5, False, False, False, False]):
    ....
```

or

```
if any(x in {} for x in [4, 5, False, False, False, False]):
    ....
```

depending on what you want

Comment: `any(x in {} for x in [4, 5, False])` returns `True`. I was surprised by this, I guess `any` considers the iterable as a whole, and an iterator is true. So it should be `any([x in {} for x in [4, 5, False]])`.

Comment: @gerrit `any(x in {} for x in [4, 5, False])` returns `False` for me, both in Python 2.7 and 3.3

Comment: @JanneKarila Aah! I was using `pylab`, which does `from numpy import *`. `numpy`s `any` is shadowing the builtin `any`.